# How can I change the icon color in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, icons, navigationview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:itemIconTint= ""
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Those icons have their original colors.

However, if set to itemIconTint = "@null", the color comes out gray.

If you delete @null, the color will come out well, but it will not be built.

I am a beginner. What should I do?

[image]

I want to make it like this.
-> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNq0R.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color you want in the same place,

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
```

I can't add a comment. So is that what youare looking for?  or what you exactly require?

Comment: I apologize for using a translator.
That icon has the original color.
However, the icon changes color because of app:itemIconTint.
How do I preserve the original color?

Comment: Right can you set the original color in app:itemIconTint="@color/icon_original_color"

Answer (score 0):

By reading a comment you've made, I understand you don't want to alter the color of the icons whatsoever.
If so, as far as I know, there is no need to even set `app:itemIconTint` at all, it's not a required field for the `NavigationView`. Have you tried removing that line?